# Is it possible to alter and update the status icon of a running indicator applet?

Tags: indicator, programming, application-development

I'm trying to create a simple application indicator that mimics the CPU load applet for the gnome-panel.

I currently do this by updating (overwriting) the status icon of the indicator with the new CPU load information and re-set the status icon to the same icon on every update (I know this is stupid, but I don't know if it's currently possible to solve otherwise).

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I always see the "first" icon state, eg.

[image]

The indicator icon doesn't update, while the icon's content does.

I also tried to temporarily set the status icon to something else first, eg.

```
...
update_icon()
indicator.set_icon("indicator-messages")
indicator.set_icon("indicator-cpu-load")
...
```

but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE:**

It is indeed possible to do what I wanted using a hack to cause the indicator to repaint its icon (thanks to Jorge Castro and Ted Gould):

```
...
update_icon()
indicator.set_status(appindicator.STATUS_ATTENTION)
indicator.set_status(appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
...
```

The attention state icon should be the same as the active state icon, else there would be some flicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed not the intended behaviour of Application Indicators: they're meant to have one or two icons and not something that you could almost put in a widget.

There seems to be something wrong in the caching of the icon, as it should update a changed icon, though.

Anyway, you probably want to use something like '[libindicator](https://launchpad.net/libindicator)' to create your own, custom indicator. The collection of application indicators on your panel is drawn by one indicator. You have a lot more functions at your disposal when writing a custom indicator, than when using the limited API of Application Indicators, which was limited deliberately to make sure we don't get a mess.

Also make sure to look at the package 'libindicator-tools', which contains some handy utilities for testing indicators.

Comment: While it _is_ possible to do what I want (see update in the question), I agree that writing a custom indicator probably is a better idea.

Comment: Still, I don't see why using an established and well functioning procedure such as GTkStatusIcon is obviously discouraged here. To put this clear again: at present there is full support for GtkStatusIcon in all major desktop managers. Therefore GtkStatusIcon needs to be continued in future releases of Ubuntu, and it will - at least as fallback. Whoever downvoted for GtKStatusIcon could you please explain why you think different. Are there any reasons I might not be aware of to not write programs that depend on GtkStatusIcon?

Comment: The next version of Ubuntu, which will use Unity as the default shell, will not support GtkStatusIcons, apart for Java and Wine special cases. This is done so the desktop can move forwards, using new technology and reduce clutter in the notification area.

Comment: thank you for pointing at this. Does this really mean that all applications that either need a customizable icon or that rely on a legacy NA will not run in future Ubuntu versions if their developers won't port it?

Comment: They will run on Ubuntu, but their GtkStatusIcon will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible and looks like it's by design, from the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-application/+bug/668375).

> What we instead would like to
>   encourage is for people to start
>   thinking like icon themes. The reason
>   for this is that it allows for
>   multiple sizes and theming of the
>   panel separate from applications. So,
>   for instance, an application could be
>   themed with a light background (thus
>   needing dark icons) and the panel
>   could have a dark background (needing
>   light icons). The application
>   shouldn't have to know about this. And
>   by using icon naming this problem is
>   solvable on the panel side of things.
>
> For the Natty cycle we also want to
>   provide a convenience API to provide
>   for building a custom icon theme for
>   people who want to generate icons.
>   This doesn't solve all of the theming
>   problems, but it does make it possible
>   to solve the multiple sizes one.

Update: To answer your comment Ted thinks that is a bug and recommends that you file a bug on [indicator-application](https://launchpad.net/indicator-application), something along the lines of "theme updates are not realized by the indicators"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what I do is against the design, but I'm afraid that comment doesn't answer why I cannot edit/alter an icon (within the theme), and force the indicator to update its content. I can do something like indicator.set_icon("a") indicator.set_icon("b") indicator.set_icon("c") ... but I don't have infinite space for infinite new icons. :P